# How to move a widget in the screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, move, flutter-widget

I am using flutter and i have a **container** with the shape of a circle  using this code

```
new Container(
 width: 50.0,
  height: 50.0,
   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
   shape: BoxShape.circle)
```

I want to make this circle move on the screen like this

[image]

how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Draggable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) widget. You can then handle the translation using `onDraggableCanceled` which is passed and offset that you can be  used to update the placement

```
onDraggableCanceled :(velocity,offset){ 
//update the position here
}
```

**Update**

After checking the image you will need "Drop me here" part to be a [DragTarget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html) that has a method `onAccept` which will handles the logic when you drag and drop your `Draggable`

Comment: `onDraggableCanceled` is unnecessary here.  What he want is a `DragTarget`.

Comment: Ah I figured after checking the image

Comment: @aziza Hi, how can I update the widget's new position here? I'm new to Flutter, I don't know how to set Widget's absolute position based on offset parameter. Can you provide some code here ?

Answer (score 11):

Here it is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Drag app"),
        ),
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double width = 100.0, height = 100.0;
  Offset position ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = Offset(0.0, height - 20);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: position.dx,
          //top: position.dy - height + 20,
          child: Draggable(
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(child: Text("Drag", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,),),
            ),
            feedback: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Drag", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,),),
              color: Colors.red[800],
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
            onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset){
              setState(() => position = offset);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wooh!Thts what i'm looking for!Worked well

Answer (score 3):

First, wrap your `Container` inside the `Stack` with `Positioned`.

Then, use `Pan Gesture` to implement a `Pan` in your `Container` and use `onPan...` methods to handle `Pan Gesture`

Here is code:

Offset position;

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = Offset(10, 10);
  }    

@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        double _height = _width * 9 / 16;


        return GestureDetector(
          onPanStart: (details) => _onPanStart(context, details),
          onPanUpdate: (details) => _onPanUpdate(context, details, position),
          onPanEnd: (details) => _onPanEnd(context, details),
          onPanCancel: () => _onPanCancel(context),

          child: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: position.dy,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: _width,
                    height: _height,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      void _onPanStart(BuildContext context, DragStartDetails details) {
        print(details.globalPosition.dy);

      }

      void _onPanUpdate(BuildContext context, DragUpdateDetails details, Offset offset) {
        setState(() {
          position = details.globalPosition;
        });
      }

      void _onPanEnd(BuildContext context, DragEndDetails details) {
        print(details.velocity);
      }

      void _onPanCancel(BuildContext context) {
        print("Pan canceled !!");
      }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Draggable` class for dragging the item which you want to drag and for placing it or sticking it to somewhere on the screen you have to wrap that item with `DragTarget` class. In `DragTarget` class `onAccept` method is there where you can write the logic. You can also take a reference to my code here it is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Drag Box'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(title),
      ),
      body:
          new DragGame(), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class DragGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DragGameState createState() => new _DragGameState();
}

class _DragGameState extends State<DragGame> {
  int boxNumberIsDragged;

  @override
  void initState() {
    boxNumberIsDragged = null;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildDraggableBox(1, Colors.red, new Offset(30.0, 100.0)),
            buildDraggableBox(2, Colors.yellow, new Offset(30.0, 200.0)),
            buildDraggableBox(3, Colors.green, new Offset(30.0, 300.0)),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget buildDraggableBox(int boxNumber, Color color, Offset offset) {
    return new Draggable(
      maxSimultaneousDrags: boxNumberIsDragged == null || boxNumber == boxNumberIsDragged ? 1 : 0,
      child: _buildBox(color, offset),
      feedback: _buildBox(color, offset),
      childWhenDragging: _buildBox(color, offset, onlyBorder: true),
      onDragStarted: () {
        setState((){
          boxNumberIsDragged = boxNumber;
        });
      },
      onDragCompleted: () {
        setState((){
          boxNumberIsDragged = null;
        });
      },
      onDraggableCanceled: (_,__) {
        setState((){
          boxNumberIsDragged = null;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBox(Color color, Offset offset, {bool onlyBorder: false}) {
    return new Container(
      height: 50.0,
      width: 50.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: offset.dx, top: offset.dy),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: !onlyBorder ? color : Colors.grey,
          border: Border.all(color: color)),
    );
  }
}
```